# How to test to see if packets are moving between two ports on a dual port NIC

Tags: networking, server, dns, iptables, dhcp

I'm trying to set up a home router on Ubuntu 20.04 Server.
I have followed dozens of on-line tutorials, and for the life of me, I can't get this to work.
As soon as I get everything set up, nothing works.

*Basic Setup*
Internet --> CableModem --> DualPortNIC(Top) --> DualPortNIC(Bottom) --> 24PortSwitch --> Other PC's/Devices

**NOTES:**
1/ The Dual Port NIC is set up (via Netplan) to have the "Top" port as DHCP, it get a proper IP address from my ISP.
2/ The Dual Port NIC is set up (via Netplan) to have the "Bottom" port as Static, it gets three IP addresses assigned.

> 1/ 192.168.1.1 (Gateway)
> 2/ 192.168.1.2 (DNS)
> 3/ 192.168.1.3 (NTP) (I need to re-set this up, I have rebuilt this server 12 times)

3/ I have enable IPv4 forwarding in sysctl.conf
4/ There is a NIC on the MotherBoard of this server set with a static IP address (via Netplan) of 192.168.1.61.
5/ DNSMasq is set up and appears to be functioning properly. Most devices on my network are setup to obtain their IP address, Gateway and DNS via DHCP. DNSMasq is handing out the proper addresses to devices.
6/ I *WAS* able to do a (CLI) speedtest (sitting at the PC with a monitor and keyboard) and got good results.
7/ I have tried both using UFW and/or IPTables in many different configurations/tutorials. All **without** success.

It seems as soon as I try setting up IPTables rules and/or NAT, things stop functioning. I can't ping anything outside of my network via hostname **OR** IP Address.
Sometimes, I can't even ping things on my internal network.

**So, my questions are:**
1/ Is there a way to *TEST* to see if packets are able to move between the two ports on the Dual Port NIC?
2/ Is there a *SIMPLE* way to set things up just to see if it will even work. I'm not even concerned with firewall/packet filtering for a test at this point. I just want to be able from the other PC's/Devices on my network, get out to the internet.
3/ I would like to know how to *PROPERLY* set up IPTables for my setup.

Because I don't which direction to go next, I am not including and config files in this post.
If you need to see any config files or output from tests, please don't hesitate to ask, I will be more then happy to add them as needed.

EDIT, adding requested output:

```
scott@mediapc:~$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4758 packets, 540977 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 87 packets, 7798 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8411 packets, 738185 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

scott@mediapc:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 74 packets, 14975 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 73 packets, 14850 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 202 packets, 15747 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 199 packets, 15520 bytes)
pkts bytes  target     prot opt in out      source  destination
   3   227  MASQUERADE all  --  *  enp1s0f0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: You may want to look into this program. https://linuxhint.com/install_configure_wireshark_ubuntu/

Comment: If it were me, I would just use one IP address for the "Bottom" NIC, 192.168.1.1 and have the gateway, DNS, and NTP all on the one address. I would also disable the 192.168.1.61 NIC. Yes, there is a most basic iptables rule set to start with, but give me some time to either find a reference or to write it in an answer. You will want to improve it quickly to block stuff. I would use tcpdump rather then wireshark to monitor traffic, but that is just preference.

Comment: If all of your iptables default policies are ACCEPT, then your most basic iptables rule set is: `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE` where the interface name `enp0s3` is the name of your "TOP", or internet facing, NIC. Obviously change that name to your actual interface name. Your question 3 depends on what services you have exposed to internet.

Comment: @DougSmythies I have tried your suggestions. I set the "bottom" port on the dual port NIC to .1. I shut down the .61 NIC. I added the MASQUERADE setting as described (changing the interface name to enp1s0f0 - The top port on the dual port NIC)
As soon as I get all these changes in place, from the keyboard mouse connected to this computer, I can no longer ping hostnames or IP addresses outside of my network.
I **WAS** able to "ping -I enp1s0f0 8.8.8.8". That did work.
iptables list output below...

Comment: @DougSmythies Here is the output of my iptables list. (Sorry, the formatting looks bad)
scott@mediapc:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: It would be good to see the outputs for `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL`. I want to see the packet counters. not sure why DNS is not working... Do your clients still expect it to be on .2?

Comment: Ya, to test ping from your internal network, you have to do it from a client computer. `ping -I internal-nic-name 8.8.8.8` doesn't work for me either, and my router/gateway unbuntu box does work, everything, including this typing, goes through it.

Comment: @DougSmythies here is the first output you requested.
scott@mediapc:~$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4758 packets, 540977 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 87 packets, 7798 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8411 packets, 738185 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: @DougSmythies here is the second output (part-1) you requested.
scott@mediapc:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 74 packets, 14975 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 73 packets, 14850 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: @DougSmythies here is the second output (part-2) you requested.
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 202 packets, 15747 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 199 packets, 15520 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       3      227 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp1s0f0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Comment: @DougSmythies I am not sure why DNS is not working either. I did swing it over to 192.168.1.1 for these tests. I don't have enough knowledge to know if packets not moving acoss the interface and DNS not working are the same issue or two different issues. In my current configuration, DNS works great. let me know if you would like to see the various dnsmasq and/or netplan config files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122558/discussion-between-doug-smythies-and-scott-vinzant).